# Encountering error when trying to connect a webservice to vs2010 project

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint

I need to add a webservice to my sharepoint 2010 project. But when I try it, I get the following error:

"The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM'."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:

http://ddkonline.blogspot.com/2009/11/fix-http-request-is-unauthorized-with.html